# How to manage nodejs microservices without service discovery?

Tags: node.js, microservices, service-discovery

We are developing microservices in NodeJS and deploying them to an Application server. These services run on random port which is set in config file programmatically. I know these services could be managed using service discovery like Eureka / Consul and similar. However, is there a way to manage them without using any service discovery.

Answer (score 1):

However you call it, you will need a central place where services will need to register their host and port (and deregister when they shutdown gracefully), so that others know how to consume them. You can use a database (SQL/noSQL), Eureka, Consul, anything that will give you "put data" and "get data" capabilities.

Benefit of solutions like Eureka and Consul are built-in health checks and removing service from the registry if it fails them.